# Python 2.7 code, need explanation

Tags: python, function

```
def fact( n ):
    """fact( number ) -> number

    Returns the number of permutations of n things."""
    if n == 0:
        return 1L
    return n*fact(n-1L)
```

Anyone can explain me what this code does?
I am confused about the return statement ... n*fact(n-1L)! This seems Infinite for me :/

Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with recursion? If not, this is where you want to start, and that's not a concept specific to python.

Comment: it will exit when `n == 0`

Comment: @AvinashRaj this existed in python as long `int`. Not very common (or needed) anymore.

Comment: @ReutSharabani 1st thing comes in my mind about recursion is fibonacci recursion... but this won't help me...

Comment: Fibonacci is another common example of recursion. If you understand how Fibonacci works - you should understand this as well. Fibonacci even has *two* recursive calls (in the academic implementation)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a recursive function.

### Line by line

#### Line 1: `if n == 0:`

This is pretty self explanatory. In this `if` statement, we check  to see if `n` is equal to `0`.

#### Line 2: `return 1L`

If `n` is indeed equal to `0`, we return `1L` (1 `Long`, or essentially `1` in this case.) Note, that if we get to this `return`, we do not go on to the 3<sup>rd</sup> line because a `return` is like a `break`.

#### Line 3: `return n*fact(n-1L)`

We multiply `n` times `n-1` and pass it back into the recursive function because it is checking for factorials, and we want to go all the way until `n` is 0 (`6!` shouldn't yield `6*5`, it should yield `6*5*4*3*2*1`.)

Answer (score 2):

Not infinite. It is, in fact, a classic example of inductive definition, which in programming translates into recursion. For it to work, there need to be two parts:

- Terminating condition, that describes when the problem is simple enough that we know the answer. In this case, what to do for `fact(0)`.
- Non-terminating condition, that describes how to break down a complex problem into simpler ones. In this case, look up `fact(n - 1)` and multiply by `n`.

So... let's say you have `fact(3)`. It is not terminating, so it is `3 * fact(2)`. Still not terminating, so it is `3 * (2 * fact(1))`. Still going! `3 * (2 * (1 * fact(0)))`. And there's our terminating condition, which does not call `fact` any more: `3 * (2 * (1 * (1)))`. So... not so infinite :)

Comment: Well, not inifinite for non-negative (or *whole*) input.

Comment: @ReutSharabani: Indeed. If programmed defensively, there would be some kind of an assert to enforce the function's contract. As it is... we should just force the caller to assume the universe will end if he ever tries to take a factorial of anything but a natural number.

Comment: Well, it's obvious what the point of the function is, but since OP mentioned it seemed "infiinite", it's worth to note he is not entirely wrong. Because it sometimes is.

Comment: Thank you for your time! Totally understood it :)